# What is the difference between a .ckpt and a .pth file in Pytorch?

Tags: pytorch

I am following a code from GitHub that uses Pytorch.
The model is saved using :

```py
model.save(ARGS.working_dir + '/model_%d.ckpt' % (epoch+1)).
```

What is the difference between using `.pth` and `.ckpt` in Pytorch?

Answer (score 10):

There is no difference. the extension in Pytorch models that you see is something random. You can choose anything.
People usually use `pth` to indicate a **P**y**T**orc**H** model (and hence `.pth`). but then again its completely up to you on how you want to save your model.